# How do I check if the normal vector is pointing inside or outside?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Lets say I've a sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and I need to solve an integral $\iint_S\vec F\cdot\vec ndS$. while $S$ is the sphere. 
And I can't use gauss law because $\vec F$ is not continuous at some point inside $S$. I had
$$\vec F=\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right).$$

So I went and tried to go for it normally using ball coordinates $$\vec r(\theta,\phi)=(\cos\theta \sin\phi, \sin\theta \sin\phi, \cos\phi).$$
And I found that $$r_{\theta}\times r_{\phi}=(-\cos\theta \sin^2\phi,-\sin\theta \sin^2\phi,-\sin\phi \cos\phi).$$
Now I know that this could be the normal pointing inside the ball or outside of it.

In order to try to check, I tried to reach a point $(1,0,0)$ on it, and check if the "$x$" part of the normal is positive or negative in that point.

But I got lost trying to find $\phi,\theta$ which satisfy that, and wanted to know if there's any better way to decide in what direction the normal I found is pointing.

Any feedback is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: A common way to decide the direction of a normal vector is to memorize it. When you take the cross product of two vectors, the result will always be in a certain direction. This can be determined using the right hand rule (or any other rules you invent).

Comment: Think of different common surfaces. For a paraboloid $z = x^2 + y^2$ or for a cone $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, the outward normal vector would generally point downward in the negative $z$ direction. So you should make sure $k$ component of the normal vector has the negative sign. For a sphere centered at origin, you know $(x, y, z)$ is outward. So for $z \gt 0$ you can say that it points generally in the upward direction whereas for $z \lt 0$, it points generally in the downward direction so it is outward normal vector.

Comment: @MathLover Thanks alot, that makes sense, I was also thinking of using the idea of $\theta, \phi$. so if I want to check point $(1,,0,0)$ I know for sure $\phi = \frac{\pi}{2}$, and $\theta = 0$ (as im on xy plane on $x=1,y=0$) and with that I found that this vector is pointing inwards with $\phi = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\theta = 0$. what do you think?

Comment: Yes you can do that for a check. Take any point $P(x, y, z)$ on the sphere and connect the origin $O$ (center) to this point on the sphere. Both vectors $\vec{OP}$ and $\vec {PO}$ are normal to the surface. $\vec {OP} = (x-0, y- 0, z-0)$ is pointing outward whereas $\vec {PO} = (0 - x, 0 - y, 0-z)$ is pointing inward. In your case, the unit normal vector $(-\cos\theta \sin\phi, -\sin\theta \sin\phi, -\cos\phi)$ is for a point on the surface given by $(\cos\theta \sin\phi, \sin\theta \sin\phi, \cos\phi)$ and so it is clear it is pointing towards the origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One general rule for a region $\ R\ $ defined by  $\ R=\big\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3\,\big|\,f(x)< C\,\big\}$, where $\ f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\ $ is a differentiable function, and $\ C\in\mathbb{R}\ $ a constant, is that when $\ f(x)=C\ $ and $\ \nabla f(x)\ne\vec{0}\ $, then $\ \nabla f(x)\ $ is an *outward* normal to the boundary of $\ R\ $ at the point $\ x\ $. If you get the normal at a given point in some other way, as you've done by taking the cross product of two tangents to the boundary, then the direction of the normal is *outward* if the directional derivative of $\ f\ $ at that point in the direction of the normal is *positive*, and it's an *inward* normal if the directional derivative is *negative*.  If the directional derivative is zero, then you need to look at higher order directional derivatives to tell whether $\ f\ $ is increasing or decreasing in the given direction.

In your case, with $\ S\ $ being the unit sphere, of which the inside is the open unit ball, $\ R=\big\{\,(x,y,z)\,|\,x^2+y^2+z^2<1\,\big\}\ $, you have $\ f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2\ $, and $\ 
\nabla f(x,y,z)=2\big(x\,\vec{\mathbf{i}}+y\,\vec{\mathbf{j}}+z\,\vec{\mathbf{k}}\big)=$$2\vec{r}\ $, so $\ 
\vec{r}\ $ itself, as a positive multiple $\ \frac{1}{2}\nabla f\ $ of $\ \nabla f\ $ is an outward (unit) normal. Note that your cross product,
$$
r_\theta\times r_\phi=-\sin\phi\,\vec{r}(\theta,\phi)\ ,
$$
as a *negative* multiple of $\ 
\vec{r}\ $ (for $\ 0<\phi<\pi\ $) , must be an inward normal.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the scalar product of your two vectors, $\vec r . (r_\theta \times r_\phi)$, you get a quantity which is always negative, showing the vector points inwards.
BTW you are using $\theta$ and $\phi$ the opposite way round from what I would regard as usual.

Comment: Which is which of $\theta$ and $\phi$ in spherical coordinates is very much not universal. It is more common in math to see $\theta$ as the $xy$ plane angle, so that it's basically the same as it is in polar and cylindrical coordinates, while $\phi$ is the angle against the $z$ axis. However, I know physicists are fond of the opposite convention, and I personally found that immensely confusing when I took courses in quantum mechanics and general relativity.

Comment: @RogerJBarlow Thanks for the answer, Could you explain what quantity means? because I'm a little confused as if i take for example $\theta = \pi$ I will get a positive value in the first component, but I'm not sure if I understood what you meant.

Comment: for two vectors $\vec a $ and $\vec b$, if $\vec a . \vec b$ is positive then $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are in the same direction, if it is negative they are in opposite directions.    In this case it is always negative (or, at least non-positive) as $0 \le \phi \le \pi$ . Indeed your second vector is just your first vector multiplied by $-\sin \phi$.