# Is the Normal vector is pointing inside or outside?

Tags: greens-theorem, divergence-theorem

Good morning,
I am posting this again because I am having trouble to understand this post ([How do I check if the normal vector is pointing inside or outside?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4189829/how-do-i-check-if-the-normal-vector-is-pointing-inside-or-outside)).
Here is my question :
I have the parametrization $$\sigma(r,\theta) = \left\langle r \cos \theta, r\sin \theta, \frac{r^2}{3} \right\rangle$$

I computed the cross product between $\sigma_r$ and $\sigma_\theta$ and got :
$(-\frac{2}{3}r^2 \cos \theta,-\frac{2}{3}r^2 \sin \theta, r)$ with $r$ ranging from $[0, \sqrt(3)]$ and $\theta$ from $0$ to $2 \pi$.\

I really do not understand how to get that the normal is pointing inwards or outwards, I can visualize that the normal should be pointing outward by my cross product I am unsure where it points. Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Btw: what has this to do with Green's theorem?

Comment: I was using it in the divergence theorem and they are related so i thought i could have it as a flair.

Comment: I suggest to look up Green's theorem, Gauss' theorem and Stokes' theorem. Green's theorem holds in dimension two and has nothing to do with divergence.

Answer (score 0):

Just checking:
$$
\sigma_r\times\sigma_\theta=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta\\\sin\theta\\\frac{2r}{3}\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}-r\sin\theta\\r\cos\theta\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{2r^2}{3}\cos\theta\\-\frac{2r^2}{3}\sin\theta\\r\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
There is no way of telling what we mean by "inward" or "outward". The solid that is bounded by this surface could be above or below it.
Also: who told you that the normal is $\sigma_r\times\sigma_\theta$ and not $\sigma_\theta\times\sigma_r\,?$ All we can say is that $\sigma_r\times\sigma_\theta$ points into the $z$-direction (obviously) since its $z$-component $r$ is nonnegative.

[image]

Comment: I do not see why the sign is a +, there is no correct normal as you said, I was just sticking to my previous notation...

Comment: @Ravinala . Correct. No plus sign.

Comment: This is what I was asking how do i know that my normal points in the z direction? because the z component is >0?

Comment: @Ravinala . If you have trouble seeing this I suggest to plot a few vectors with GeoGebra. How could a vector $(x,y,z)$ with $z>0$ possibly point into the *negative* $z$-direction? What is the sign of $z$ (aka $r$) in your case?